# Querying a collection by id of one of its members

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

A Firestore collection `activities` contains a field called `member`. That field is a Document Reference to a document in the `members` collection.

Is there a way to filter all activities for that member if all I have is the member document id?

E.g. something like:

```
firebase.collection('activities').where('member.id', '==', memberId)
```

The closest I got was

```
firebase.collection('activities').where('member', '==', firebase.collection('members').document(memberId)
```

but that constitutes an extra read operation.

Comment: So you want to get all activities and member data in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code `firebase.collection('members').document(memberId)` sets up a `DocumentReference`. It does **not** yet read that document, so there's no charge for it.

Your last snippet looks correct to me: to find all activities with a reference to a specific member, you need to set up a `DocumentReference` to that member's document.